# Why am I not getting an output when reading from a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to read from a file and print it for the user to read. My task is similar to the UNIX 'cat' command but my code does not print anything.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h> //for printf

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
  int fd;
  char buffer;

  if(argc==1)
    fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
  else
    if (fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY) ==0){
    printf("Error opening");
    return(0);
  }

  while((read(fd,&buffer,1)) != -1){
     read(fd,&buffer,1);
     write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer, 1);

  }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: That has... a number of issues, some of which your compiler will tell you about if you turn on warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good start for gcc and clang).

Comment: `if(argc==1) fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);` It's not legal to access `argv[1]` if `argc < 2`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja If `argc` is 1, then `argv[1]` is guaranteed to be a null pointer. Not something you should pass to `open`, certainly, but just accessing it is legal.

Comment: Ah, I've never relied on the null pointer behavior. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Having a buffer of size 1 is somewhat slow when doing `read`/`write`. Every call is a kernel <-> userspace context switch with complex error handling. It is recommended to use larger buffers with even more complex error handling. Luckily, libc  already provides such buffers that are simple to use. Use file streams with `fopen` and `fclose`, and then you can do single byte IO with `fgetc` and `fputc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading from the wrong FD due to a precedence issue. `if (fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY) ==0)` is parsed as `if (fd=(open(argv[1],O_RDONLY) ==0))`. You wanted it to be parsed as `if ((fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY)) ==0)` instead, so write that.

Other problems:

- `0` is a legitimate FD. You should check against `-1` instead to see if `open` failed.
- If `argc` is 1, then `argv[1]` is a null pointer, which you shouldn't try to `open`.
- Calling `read` twice in a row instead of just once means you're going to throw away every other character.
- `write` expects a pointer, so pass it `&buffer` too like you do with `read`. Remember it's not `printf`.
- `read` can return 0 when you get to EOF, and right now that will send your program into an infinite loop printing the final character.